# How to remove .aar file form Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, aar

I have added `.aar` file in Android Studio. Its creating some conflict. Now i want to remove this `.aar` file, but i am unable to find out any option to delete this file.

I have also searched this, but unable to find out any solution to delete `.aar` file

Comment: What do you mean you have a `.aar` file in Android Studio. Can you post a screenshot of what you see? Perhaps, the easiest would be to use Windows Explorer or Finder to delete the file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***1. Open Project Structure via  File -> Project Structure ,***

[image]

***2. Remove library module dependency from app(Main) module ,***

[image]

**3. Remove ARR library module,**

[image]

***4. Finally go to project file path in your harddrive Remove manually ARR library module,***

Comment: what is the difference from simply remove the dependency from gradle file ?

Comment: @OmarBeshary Absolutely nothing.